# Terraform azurerm_function_app_function deleting itself after deployment

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions

TLDR: azurerm_function_app_function will work fine on Terraform Apply, but disappears from Azure Portal afterwards.

I am trying to deploy an Azure Function via Terraform for months now and have not had any luck with it.

The Terraform apply will run fine. I will then go into the Azure Portal and look at the function app functions and this function will be there. However when I refresh the blade the function will disappear. I have made the same function and deployed it via VS Code no issues, but with Terraform there is no luck.

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "main" {
  name                = "tf-linux-app"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.main.id

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_access_key

  site_config {
    app_scale_limit          = 200
    elastic_instance_minimum = 0
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.9"
    }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "${azurerm_storage_account.main.name}_STORAGE" = azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_connection_string
  }
  client_certificate_mode = "Required"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "main" {
  name            = "tf-BlobTrigger"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.main.id
  language        = "Python"

  file {
    name    = "__init__.py"
    content = file("__init__.py")
  }
  test_data = "${azurerm_storage_container.container1.name}/{name}"

  config_json = jsonencode({
    "scriptFile" : "__init__.py",
    "disabled": false,
    "bindings" : [
      {
        "name" : "myblob",
        "type" : "blobTrigger",
        "direction" : "in",
        "path" : "${azurerm_storage_container.container1.name}/{name}",
        "connection" : "${azurerm_storage_container.container1.name}_STORAGE"
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

As far as the Python script, I'm literally just trying
[the demo found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example)
that Azure provides.

__init__.py:

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info('Python Blob trigger function processed %s', myblob.name)
```

I tried running Terraform apply, I expected the function app to appear and stay there, but it appears and then disappears. I also tried deploying a C# function to a Windows app. This worked as expected, but I now need the script in Python.

Comment: Can you use [Azure Monitor Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log) to monitor the changes to your function? I'm not sure if this information is actually captured by Activity Logs but if so it may give some insight into what exactly is deleting the object.